# how to add the background image in gui in java

Tags: java

I made this log in form in java and I want to add background image in it I try but no avail. how can I make it possible?

```
 import javax.swing.*;

    import java.awt.*;

    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class LogIn extends JFrame {

        JFrame f;
        JTextField t1, t2;
        JButton btn;
        JLabel lbl1, lbl2,img;

        public LogIn() {

    //        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            img = new JLabel
            (new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\AF Computer\\Downloads\\picture.jpg"));

            f = new JFrame("LogIn Form");
            lbl1 = new JLabel("User Name:");
            t1 = new JTextField();
            lbl2 = new JLabel("Password:");
            t2 = new JTextField();
            btn = new JButton("Log In");

            lbl1.setBounds(10, 80, 70, 30);
            t1.setBounds(80, 80, 250, 30);
            lbl2.setBounds(10, 130, 70, 30);
            t2.setBounds(80, 130, 250, 30);
            btn.setBounds(230, 200, 100, 40);
            f.add(img);
            f.add(lbl1);
            f.add(lbl2);
            f.add(t1);
            f.add(t2);
            f.add(btn);
             f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setSize(1000, 700);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setResizable(false);

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new LogIn();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does not work? You get an exception?

Comment: no exception but not adding image too...

Comment: (1) Make sure the image is loaded correctly. (2) Use a proper layout manager. Using null layout manager will cause you many problems in the future.

Comment: ok but help me in it please...

Comment: I am still examining your code, but I can't check if you load your image correctly. You have to test it yourself by debugging. It's a local thing.

Comment: Currently in your code you are not setting the bounds for the `img` label, so it doesn't show. However, while you're at it, just choose a layout manager that better suits you. If you can show ASCII art or a mockup image of what you want the result to look like we would be able to direct you better.

Comment: @RozeenaMalik Take a look at my solution and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are setting bounds for your JLabels, but not `img`. If you are not using any layout for your JFrame, you will have to set the bounds for `img` label as well, else with the default layout from the JFrame, only one of the components will be shown.

Add the following codes (if you decided to use absolute positioning):

```
this.setLayout(null);
img.setBounds(/*your bounds*/);
```

If is also advisable to extends from a JPanel and add the panel into the JFrame instead of making a new subclass for JFrame.